# Ionic Countdown Timer App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im programming a Countdown app with ionic, Im not good in AngularJS and because of that, i dont know what i did wrong :/
Maybe you can take a look at my code, it should have a button, which starts the countdown, and if the countdown is finished, a message should pop up.

## timer.js

```
    angular.module('PopupTimer', [])

.controller('PopupCtrl',function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {

    $scope.showAlert = function() {
     var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Your Pizza Is Ready!',
       template: 'Bon Appétit!'
     });

     alertPopup.then(function(res) {
       console.log('Pizza Is Ready!');
     });
   };

    $scope.timerCountdown = function(res){
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Your Pizza Is Ready!',
       template: 'Bon Appétit!'});

      var endtimer = $timeout([200]);

      if(endtimer == ([0])) {
       return showAlert();
      }
  }
});
```

## app.js

```
    // Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

  // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
  // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
  // a much nicer keyboard experience.
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}


 });
})
```

## index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="PopupTimer">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/timer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-assertive">
        <h1 class="title">Pizza Timer</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="PopupCtrl">
        <button class="button button-full button-light" ng-click="timerCountdown">
          Alert
        </button>
      </ion-content>    
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation of $timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), you'll see that its first parameter is a function, which should be invoked after the specified delay.

The delay (second parameter) is specified in milliseconds. So to show an alert after 5 seconds, your `$sope.timerCountdown` function would look like this:

```
$scope.timerCountdown = function(res){
  var endtimer = $timeout(
    function() {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Your Pizza Is Ready!',
       template: 'Bon Appétit!'});
    },
    5000);
};
```

Comment: But it still gives me errors and dont shows the app up (link: http://i.imgur.com/68voVXv.png)

Comment: @JulianBe: don't know what the problem is, it must be in another part of the app (not in timerCountdown). Have a look at this minimal example: http://play.ionic.io/app/57ca9c1973c5 - maybe you can see the difference.

Comment: I have another question, do you know how i display how much time is left?